# How to fix the iPad home screen being dark purple?

Tags: ipad, screen, display

My iPad Mini's home screen is really dark and I think it's because of something I have done.

I have removed emoji keyboard as I thought that was causing it but the darkness still remains.

Comment: If you are not able to comment, you can alwsys edit your own question. If an answers works for you, you can say thanks by voting up the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

**brightness**

It sounds like you have your brightness turned down.

To change your screen brightness, tap Settings > Display & Brightness and drag the slider to the right or left.

See: [support.apple.com brightness](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202613)